# Different behavior with JQuery 1.4.4 and 2.1.1 (scroll top)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Don't ask me why, but a developer I commissioned used JQuery 1.4.4 to set up a couple functions on a page, and I am trying to update the JQuery version to 2.1.1.  Doing this, I am getting a couple JS errors that are dealing with scrolling, namely:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var scroll_pos = 0;
            $(document).scroll(function() { 
                scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
                var hrt = $('.boxBg').offset().top-200;
                if(scroll_pos > hrt) {

                    $('i.fa-heart').addClass('individual-heart-hover');
                }
                else{
                    $('i.fa-heart').removeClass('individual-heart-hover');
                }
});
});
```

and

```
var _rys = jQuery.noConflict();
        _rys("document").ready(function () {
            _rys(window).scroll(function () {
                if (_rys(this).scrollTop() >100) {
                    _rys('.navbar').addClass("f-nav");
                    _rys('.discoverSection').addClass("f-nav2");
                    $('.tabsection').css('display','block');
                } else {
                    _rys('.navbar').removeClass("f-nav");
                     _rys('.discoverSection').removeClass("f-nav2");
                     $('.tabsection').css('display','none');
                }
            });
        });
```

The lines that are receiving errors are:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

and

```
$('.tabsection').css('display','block');
```

both are receiving errors saying "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Strangely, these both work flawlessly with JQuery 1.4.4.

Comment: Is it something to do with the "jQuery.noConflict();" ? (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: use `jQuery` instead of `$` and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is suspicious:

```
var _rys = jQuery.noConflict();
```

That code *removes* the definition of `$`, so any subsequent code that uses `$` will fail.

You should only use `jQuery.noConflict()` if you need to load two different versions of jQuery simultaneously, or if you are using another library that defines `$` to mean something else. (`.noConflict()` actually restores any previous definition of `$`, but from the error you received it looks like there was no previous `$`.)

Assuming you are not dealing with one of those special situations, simply remove the `noConflict` line completely, and then change every instance of `_rys` to `$`.